# AWS returns only one region availability zones

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get all available zones of EC2 servers but api call returns only availability zones of one region

```
AWS::EC2.new.availability_zones.to_a.map(&:name)
=> ["us-east-1b", "us-east-1c", "us-east-1d"]
```

Comment: Did that solve your problem? Let me know if it didn't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon distinguishes between "regions" and "Availability zones". From [Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html) documentation:

Each **Region** contains multiple distinct locations called **Availability Zones**. Each Availability Zone is engineered to be isolated from failures in other Availability zones and to provide inexpensive, low-latency network connectivity to 
other zones in the same Region

You can use the Ruby SDK to see which regions are available for your account:

```
AWS::EC2.new.regions.map(&:name)
```

The default region is us-east-1; you can access other regions like this:

```
ec2 = AWS::EC2.new(:region => "us-west-1")
ec2.instances.create(:image_id => 'ami-3bc9997e')
```